# arbor.js z-order

Tags: z-order, arbor.js

I am using arbor.js, specifically I am using nearest to mouse to detect which node the mouse is over and highlight it, all good.

My problem is I would like to ensure the node under mouse is on top, i.e. the last drawn, so it is not obscured by other nodes. Has anyone had any luck finding a way to alter the draw order, or z-order of a node?

Cheers Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems true Z-order is not possible, best that can be done is to sort the nodes, the last node in the list will be rendered last.

Have to use an array rather than json when loading data if you want to preserve the order.

D3 has an inbuilt sort function which goes some way to address this, I think arbor could use the same.